# How do I make bitcoind listen on 0.0.0.0:8332?

Tags: bitcoin

I'm running `bitcoind` on one machine and would like to control it from another (using python and the JSON RPC interface).

`~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.config` on the bitcoind host (192.168.2.4):

```
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxx
gen=1
rcpallowip=127.0.0.1
rcpallowip=192.168.2.6   # This is the other machine
paytxfee=0.01
```

Now, I start `bitcoind -daemon`, but my python program fails with

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

On the bitcoind host, ps -nlp shows bitcoind listening on 127.0.0.1:8332, and not 0.0.0.0:8332 (which is what I would have expected). Wireshark shows a response of RST,ACK to the TCP connection attempt, which appears to be logical.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Blomkvist I agree. The target host is apparently denying the connection attempt.

Comment: Note: there is a [bitcoin stackexchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30763/bitcoin-crypto-currency) where that kind of question will be welcome.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try rpcallowip, instead of rcpallowip :)

Comment: Doh! [Squashes bug with facepalm...] --- Thank you, that works.

Comment: Nowadays, rpcbind=0.0.0.0 is also needed

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain `bitcoind` is not listening on 0.0.0.0 as well? On a fresh install here it's listening on 0.0.0.0:8333

```
$ sudo netstat --ip -lpa|grep bitcoin
tcp        0      0 localhost:8332     *:*       LISTEN      2909/bitcoind       
tcp        0      0 *:8333             *:*       LISTEN      2909/bitcoind
```

Also, what does `nmap` from 192.168.2.6 say?

Comment: As I understand it, 8333 is the peer-to-peer port for the Bitcoin network, while 8332 is the JSON/RPC port. Your netstat looks just like mine. Nmap doesn't detect anything on port 8332.

Comment: Hmm, you're quite right. A quick look at the sample code on https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29 gives one the impression that the JSON API isn't intended to be available to anything other than localhost . Deliberate design-decision or coding oversight? Maybe the only answer is to do it via a SOCKS service running on the bitcoin server...

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense, given the rpcallowip option in the config. Of course, it might still be work-in-progress. This *does* work OK on a local machine (127.0.0.1).

Comment: So is it certain that you can not access the Bitcoin server via rpc remotely? I can access my server locally through rpc but get a curl: (7) couldn't connect to host error when I try to access it remotely with a similar command (just the address changed)

Answer (score 1):

Just had same problem.

Solved by setting

```
rpcallowip=*
```

in bitcoin.conf

have a look at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon

Comment: Thanks, Michael. My problem was a simple typo: rCp for rPc

Comment: This is not supported anymore since 0.10.0

Answer (score -1):

*Please use the following settings.*

*As for http/https rpc request.*

```
rpcport=8332  #8331 will be nice.
```

*As for process.*

```
port=8332
```

*Remind:*

*1st: These two setting should not be the same.*

*2nd: You should restart the bitcoind process since you change the conf file.*

Answer (score -1):

Just Update ur bitcoin.conf file

- use rpcport = 8332  rpcconnect = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score -1):

rpcallowip=* 
It is not a good idea because it open for every one . So if you want to specific IP and Port then edit your coin.conf file 
rpcallowip = yourip; // (Default = 127.0.0.1 
rpcport = your port; // (Default =8332)

Comment: Thanks for your concern. It's OK, in my case, because it's on my local network, behind a firewall, with no port mapping.

Comment: Just a note, not all daemon allow rpcallowip=*.  dogecoin doesn't and will throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by setting

```
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
```

in bitcoin.conf